# What will be the absolute gravity of Io moon if Jupiter's gravity not in effect? Can GR explain it?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, estimation, moon, jupiter

It is noted that the distance between Io moon to Jupiter planet and our Moon to Earth is nearly same. However, the ratio of gravity Earth/Moon is 80.4 times vs ratio of gravity Jupiter/Io is 20276.7. That means Jupiter has reduced Io’s gravity by 0.68N vs Earth has reduced Moon’s gravity by 0.0027N. That means Io’s absolute gravity is 1.8+0.68=2.48N vs Moon’s absolute gravity is 1.62+0.0027=1.6227N. How this is explained in Einstein's GR?

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational field is not measured in $\mathrm N$, it has units of $\mathrm m \mathrm s^{-2}$ or $\mathrm N \mathrm {kg}^{-1}$.

Your question doesn't require general relativity, only Newtonian gravity.

All of these bodies are free-falling. Therefore an observer at the surface of Earth's moon feels no effect at all from the gravitational field of the earth. They are free-falling along with the moon in the Earth's field.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations.